# TBB concurrent hash map template arguments

Tags: c++, tbb

I'm attempting to use the TBB concurrent_hash_map container. Following this [example](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/tbb_userguide/concurrent_hash_map.htm), it is indicated that I require 3 type parameters (template arguments), the key and value types as well a trait type HashCompare. In [this](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/tbb_userguide/More_on_HashCompare.htm) link, it says that the HashCompare has defaults for basic types.

However, when attempting to use it in either of the two ways (2 or 3 template arguments) I receive an error regarding "Too few template arguments, expected 4" - and indeed upon digging through the code, the only definition of the concurrent_hash_map in the header file that I could find has four arguments:

```
class concurrent_hash_map<Key,T,HashCompare,Allocator>
```

Am I missing something, is the example simply outdated?

Answer (score 2):

There is another declaration somewhere with defaults for the last two arguments.  Make sure you include the necessary header file:

```
#include <tbb/concurrent_hash_map.h>
```

In my version of TBB, that file has:

```
template<typename Key, typename T, typename HashCompare = tbb_hash_compare<Key>, typename A = tbb_allocator<std::pair<Key, T> > >
class concurrent_hash_map;
```